A confusion about the chaotic invariant set
Consider $(M,d)$ to be a metric space, and we have a continuous map $f: M\to M$ . Then we say that $A\subset M$ is invariant under $f$ if it has property $f(A)\subset A$ .
Also, if $A\subset M$ , we say $f|_{A}: A\to A$ is chaotic if we have
1）sensitive on initial contidion
2）topologically transitive
3）dense periodic points
By this definition, we can see that if a set $A$ is chaotic, it must first be an invariant set, but not all invariant sets are chaotic. Thus, I'm wondering that
1）Do we require that $f(A)=A$ when we define chaos?
2）If we don't require $f(A)=A$ . Then if $A$ is a chaotic invariant set, must we have $f(A)=A$ ? Since $A$ is already being invariant, we already have $f(A)\subset A$ . Then by the 3 conditions for being chaotic, it is possible to prove that $f(A)= A$ ?
